# Google Cloud Storage 403 forbidden using service account- Works locally but not when deployed as a cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a script that pulls data from a third party API and writes it to a big query table. I am overwriting the BQ table every execution to include the most recent data, but am looking to store historic data in Cloud Storage.

I have seen multiple topics on this error but I can't see any that are having the same issue I have. I have granted the Service account permissions to create objects and when running the function locally, have successfully uploaded multiple objects to the bucket. However, when I try to deploy this as cloud function (using the "test function" functionality), I receive the 403 Forbidden error. The cloud function uses the same service account to access other GCP services (including BQ). The error I recieve is 'Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, 308.

Here are a the relevant parts of my code.

```
def insert_stats(request):

    environment = os.environ.get('env', 'none')
    project_id="proj_id"

    #if dev environment obtain credentails locally, else retrieve from cloud funciton environment
    if(environment == 'dev'):
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        "path"
        )
        pandas_gbq.context.credentials = credentials
        secret_client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient(credentials=credentials)
        storage_client = storage.Client(project=project_id, credentials=credentials)
        
    elif environment=="prod":
        secret_client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
        logging_client = logging.Client()
        storage_client = storage.Client(project=project_id)
        logger = logging_client.logger("ingest_log")
```

I'm setting env=dev as an environment variable locally, and env=prod for the cloud function

```
    #json_file = json.dumps(list, indent=4)
    
    #bucket = storage_client.bucket("bucket")
    #blob = bucket.blob("list_"+ str(rpt_strt.date()) + "_" + str(rpt_strt.hour) + "-00.json")
    #blob.upload_from_string(json_file)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, I don't recommend you to use a if in your code. Especially because the behavior is not the same locally and in the cloud because of the IF and you have this kind of error. To solve this, create an environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` set to the path of your file locally. And keep only the piece of PROD code. Test it locally, and when it works, it should work on Cloud Functions

Comment: Thanks for replying @guillaumeblaquiere. I previously had trouble setting this as an environment variable locally which is why I have been using `service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file`. I will attempt to again, but just wanted to check, will I not just run into the same issue? I.e. Locally, in VS I have to explicitly state the credentials, where as in the cloud function the credentials are inferred from the service account being used, and not explicitly stated. Appreciate your help, I'm new to using gcp, so best practise advice is appreciated.

Comment: I [wrote an article on the best practices](https://medium.com/google-cloud/the-2-limits-of-iam-service-on-google-cloud-7db213277d9c). In short, when you avoid to store secret, it's better! I have spotted only 2 use cases where you need a service account key file. And in your case, you don't need one!

Comment: Hello, I also think it could be great to check documentation on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#changing_default_permissions), this can be helpful if you need to set more roles/permissions for the service account of the Cloud Function.